# CakePHP Bake with Cygwin on Windows 7

Tags: cakephp, cygwin

I've been working with CakePHP for a few weeks now and I really enjoy it. I skipped over the Bake Console figuring that I'd learn more if I wrote everything by hand. Now I'd like to actually use this tool so I setup an alias in my Cygwin profile but every time I type `cake bake` it just hangs. I can't even use task manager to exit out of the Cygwin process.

I added `alias cake="C:/xampp/php/php.exe; C:/xampp/htdocs/cake_1_2/cake/console/cake.bat"` to the Cygwin .profile and also added `C:\xampp\php; C:\xamp\htdocs\cake_1_2\cake\console` to my environment path.

Any guidance or anecdotal experience would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I switched to the basic cmd in Windows 7 and it works fine. I don't know why Cygwin is choking like that but I'm happy.

Comment: am sorry , that may sounds noob question. but where do you add the alias cake= ..... line ??

Comment: I agree, cygwin is overkill here, the plain windows cmd works fine here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alias cake="c:/cygwin/path_to_your_cake/console/cake.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but shouldn't the alias in Cygwin be something like `alias cake="./cygdrive/c/path/to/executables/"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that's not the problem. The odd thing is how the terminal gives me no feedback or pathway out. There's no error or anything. It just hangs and won't let me escape out of it.